# html5 drag and drop drag anything opacity

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I am using html5 drag and drop to drag and drop div elements. On the dragstart event I set the the opacity of the div element to 0.4 which reduces makes the div element lighter but it is not transparent ie. when I drag the div element over other div elements I can't see the elements in the background.

```
var cols = document.querySelectorAll('.draggablediv');
[].forEach.call(cols, function(col) {  
col.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {this.style.opacity =
'0.4'; return true;}, false); });
```

I am using chrome 17.0.963.56.

**Edit Note:** This does not happen in firefox

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a tutorial that features the same code you are using at:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

If you load the link above in Firefox, you'll notice the examples do not work.  The tutorial features a specific mention of Firefox and why the examples don't work - you'll need to "wire up" the dataTransfer object.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my question. The drag and drop functionality is working fine in both chrome and firefox. My question was around the issue of transparency when dragging the elements. Thanks